# CSS/HTML Left and Right Float?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I can't quite seem to figure out how to do the CSS from the Photoshop mockup that I made. The image below shows what I want to accomplish. Basically, each Design/Revision block is a styled `<li>` tag, and I want to float the title to the left and the date/time to the right. Furthermore, I want everything to be vertically aligned.

Any ideas? I tried to use a table within each `<li>`, but that didn't seem to work (or I just did it wrong).

Ideas?

[image]

Comment: I assume you want something other than [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EjVFW/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/2Yec6/), should be what you are trying to do!

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="" class="clearfix">
            Design 1
            <span>May 6, 2012<br>11:34AM</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title=""class="clearfix">
            Revision 1
            <span>May 7, 2012<br>2:14AM</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    display: block;
    width: 240px;
    background-color: #212121;
    border: 1px solid #212121;
    border-top: 1px solid #444;
}
li a {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li span {
    float: right;
    font-size: 10px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 12px;
    color: #999;
    text-align: right;
}

/* helpers */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after  {
  content: '\0020';
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

Analise the CSS to learn more about float and document work-flow!

Read more about it:

[CSS Float](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)

[Document Flow / Visual Formating](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html)

**And the print screen:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Html:

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <span class="title">Design</span>
      <span class="date">2012 may 15</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

in css:

```
li .title{
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
}
li .date{
  float: right;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: use a heading and a date element for this.

Comment: @Sparky672 a heading is HTML1.0 (I thought)

Comment: @WouterJ, Of course I'm talking about the <date> element which **is** HTML5!

Answer (score 1):

I would create two div tags that have a width of 50% and are floatted to their respective sides.  So our markup would be.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="title">
            Title
        </div>
        <div class="date">
            May 10
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then we just use the following CSS to style it.

```
.title,
.date {
    width: 50%;
}

.title {
    float: left;
}

.date {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question title was on the spot :)

To do such a thing, you could use the [`float`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/float) property

With the following Markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="name">Design</div>
        <div class="time">01/01/2011</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="name">Revision</div>
        <div class="time">01/01/2012</div>
    </li>
<ul>​
```

And Css:

```
.name{
    float:left;
}

.time{
    float:right;
}

li{
    clear:both;        
}
```

That should do the trick.

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/a4eXm/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        p {
            margin: 0;
        }

        #revision_block li {
            height: 50px;
            width: 250px;
            background: url("path/to/your/background_image.jpg/png") top left no-repeat;
            display: block;
        }

        #revision_block li .title {
            font-size: 20px;
            padding-top: 13px;
            color: #eae; /*your color*/
            position: relative;
            float: left;
        }

        .date {
            text-align: right;
            float: right;
            padding-top: 7px;
        }

        .date p {
            border: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 18px;
            color: #eae; /*your color*/
        }

        .clearfix:after {
                content: ".";
                display: block;
                clear: both;
                visibility: hidden;
                line-height: 0;
                height: 0;
        }

        .clearfix {
                display: inline-block;
        }

        html[xmlns] .clearfix {
                display: block;
        }

        * html .clearfix {
                height: 1%;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <ul id="revision_block">
        <li class="clearfix">
            <p class="title">Design 1</p>
            <div class="date">
                <p>May 6, 2012</p>
                <p>11:34</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="clearfix">
            <p class="title">Design 1</p>
            <div class="date">
                <p>May 6, 2012</p>
                <p>11:34</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you made each `<li>` a block element and then inside there put two `<div>`'s, floating one to the left and one to the right?

```
<li style="dislpay:block;">
    <div style="float:left;">Design 1</div>
    </div style="float:right;">May 6, 2012</div>
</li>
```

Comment: avoid using inline CSS. And div's are really bad. Use some heading and the date element

Comment: @WouterJ, I agree that inline code should be avoided.  Please explain why _"div's are really bad"_.

Comment: @Sparky672 divisions have no special semantic meaning. The title (Design 1) has a meaning of title here. So you need to use an element which semantic meaning is a title, that are the headings (h1 - h6). The date represends a date so need to be in a date element. That's the optimal semantic. Divisions should only be use when there is no semantic element matching the goal of the element and it is a block. A title and a date are not really blocks and there are elements with beter semantic meaning, so in this examples div's are bad.

Comment: kd7iwp, you have a stray `/` inside your second `div` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `<li>` tag. Do something like this

```
<li>
    <div class='a'>
    </div>
    <div class='b'>
    </div>
</li>
```

Float both a and b to left. If required the container as well. Remember this might force you to specify width. If not you can use display:inline-block

Answer (score 0):

You put the title on `float: left;` and the date on `float: right;`. Some example:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h4>Design 1</h4>
    <date datetime="2012-05-06T11:34:00">May 6, 2012 <span>11:34 AM</span></date></li>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Revision 1</h4>
    <date datetime="2012-05-07T14:14:00">May 7, 2012 <span>2:14 AM</span></date></li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now you add this style:

```
li h4
{
    float: left;
}
li date
{
    float: right;
}
```

---

Or if you don't want to use HTML5 (I don't see why not):

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h4>Design 1</h4>
    <span class="date">May 6, 2012 <span>11:34 AM</span></span></li>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Revision 1</h4>
    <span class="date">May 7, 2012 <span>2:14 AM</span></span></li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And add a `.` before `date` in the CSS.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that `<date>` is HTML5 code and won't work in all browsers.

Comment: @Sparky672 because you give the date a float value it gets `display: block;` and then you can style them as if a browser supports it. So it doesn't needs to be mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, you want to `float` your items their respective directions using container `<div>'s`. Then you set the left margin and vertical alignment for the left item, and the right margin and vertical alignment of the right item.

That's the basics of it, I can't go into too detail on my phone. I might edit this later.

Comment: So don't post an answer if you can't fully answer it.

Comment: Who needs a full answer for something as simple as this?

Comment: The OP.  He asked the question "how?" and then accepted another answer which was complete with code, explanation, documentation and demo.

Comment: Which the OP didn't learn at all how to do, he merely asked for some code, and got it. This site isn't about giving away answers, it's about problem solving.